# Why am I seeing "Create Service Reseller channel 2c95500b-ea86-4b13-8bb5-b2f0c2fa8200 is invalid." whenever I am trying to open a cloud obj storage?

Tags: ibm-watson

Although I have created one manually, but am unable to link it to my project.
Please help me solve the issue. I'm stuck in the middle of a project for this and really don't want to miss the deadline.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do? What did you do to achieve this? And when is the error occured?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking IBM Cloud Object Storage to Watson Studio new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770694/linking-ibm-cloud-object-storage-to-watson-studio-new-project)

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue today.

I was able to find a workaround on this page:

[image]

If you click on the `Cloud Object Storage` link at the bottom of the page under `Choose project options` you will be taken to another page where you can create a Cloud Object Storage and creating from this page worked for me.

After you have created you will need to return to the page shown above and click `refresh`.

I'm not sure why this issue occurs, I can only assume some value is not being set correctly when trying to create a Cloud Object Storage via the `Add` button on the aforementioned page.