# Linking IBM Cloud Object Storage to Watson Studio new project?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-studio, cloud-object-storage

I've attempted to create object storage for a new Watson Studio project, but get the same 'Reseller channel...is invalid' as other comments.

I've tried changing my region from Dallas, to London or Tokyo as one answer suggested, but I get an 'Unexpected response code: 500' message.  I can create an object storage, using the manual workaround here:  https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/cloud-object-storage

But then how do I select this object storage when I create my new project?  I can see the storage in my Resources List, but don't know how to link it to new projects in Watson Studio.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating a new project On Watson Studio, you will see an option under **Define Storage** to Add a cloud Object Storage service to your project in the project creation page.
Once you click Add, you can either use an existing Service as you have now or create a new COS service.

[image]

For more details instructions check [this section](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-create-deploy-retrain-machine-learning-model#import_data_project) of the solution tutorial

Comment: It appears I'm able to only Create, when I click "Define Storage":

Comment: When you click Add under Define storage, you should see a page with two tabs existing and new. Do you only see new ? Can you share a screenshot ?

Comment: Okay, after logging out then logging back in, I can do that option.  Thanks!