# Getting an error "Reseller channel 2c95500b-ea86-4b13-8bb5-b2f0c2fa8200 is invalid." when I try to create a cloud object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, cloud-object-storage

I created the watson service and went to create a new project. It expects me to add Cloud Object Storage. When I chose the Lite option and press create I get this error "Reseller channel 2c95500b-ea86-4b13-8bb5-b2f0c2fa8200 is invalid."

My goal here is to setup the Watson service in order to play with Visual Recognition dk service. But I am stuck at this stage.

Can someone help with some suggestion of what else can I try or what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking IBM Cloud Object Storage to Watson Studio new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770694/linking-ibm-cloud-object-storage-to-watson-studio-new-project)

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this a few minutes ago.
And Cloud Object Storage link at the bottom of the page under Choose project options won't help,

but i found another solution that works for me

Go to https://www.ibm.com/cloud/object-storage/pricing

and click Order IBM Cloud Object Storage at bottom of the page

[image]

I hope this can solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. This helped when I went from the https://www.ibm.com/cloud/object-storage/pricing page and in the section "Provision an IBM Cloud Object Storage service instance" at the bottom of the page, I clicked on "Order IBM Cloud  Object Storage" and it appeared to goto the same provisioning page but this time it created it w/o the reseller error. Thansk!